# why after delete in the list i must refresh the page manually?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

hi in my crud system delete action in working fine but when i press delete in front look like nothing happend. but i want when press remove as item remove in back remove immediately in front.

i define one action with axios.delete.
i have not a reducer because in toturial i watch he dont define a reducer for delete

this is my code

```js
//action
export const REMOVE_BOOK = 'REMOVE_BOOK';
export const removeBook = (id) => {
  const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}`);
  return {
    type: REMOVE_BOOK,
    payload: id
  }
};


//bookList component
class BooksList extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.props.fetchBooks();
  };
  
  render() {
    if (!this.props.books) {
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Link to='create' className='btn btn-success'> Create new Book</Link>
        <table className='table table-secondary table-hover'>
          <thead>
          <tr className='bg-info text-center'>
            <td>remove</td>
            <td>title</td>
            <td>id</td>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.props.books.map((book) => {
            return (
              <tr key={book.id} className=' text-center'>
                <td>
                  <button className='btn btn-danger'
                          onClick={() => {
                            this.props.removeBook(book.id);
                          }}
                  >remove
                  </button>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Link to={`books/${book.id}`}>{book.title}
                  </Link>
                </td>
                <td>{book.id}</td>
              </tr>
            )
          })}
          </tbody>
        </table>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state.books.all);
  return {books: state.books.all}
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchBooks, removeBook})(BooksList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `separate reducer` for `Remove` action, but you need to handle the remove action in your books reducers like

```
//action
export const REMOVE_BOOK = 'REMOVE_BOOK';
export const removeBook = (id) => {
  const request = axios.delete(`${ROOT_URL}/${id}`);
  return {
    type: REMOVE_BOOK,
    payload: id
  }
};

//reducer
const booksReducer = (state = {all: []}, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        ...

        case REMOVE_BOOK: {
            const newBooks = state.all.filter(book => book.id !== action.payload)
            return {
               ...state,
               all: newBooks
            } 
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: tanx it is working run local-server again and it is working tanx a lot

Comment: Never add impure functions to your reducers. It's an anti-pattern and should be avoided! Call filter in an action creator instead.